# Get Ethernet adapter IPv4 address without using external libraries

Tags: python, sockets, udp

I have 2 computers connected with crossover cable and first time I need to start PC1 as server and PC2 as client and then second time PC2 as server and PC1 as client. I use UDP socket and it is on Windows. So I cant just put IP in code, I need the server code to get the IP automatically.

I tried this:

```
hostname = socket.gethostname()    
IPAddr = socket.gethostbyname(hostname)
```

But this gives me wrong IP. I need the IP address that I see when I check Ethernet adapter Ethernet in ipconfig/all.

I'm not sure if you understand me sorry. English is not my best skill.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try using the `netifaces` package. Docs are [here](https://pypi.org/project/netifaces/).

```
import netifaces

ip = netifaces.ifaddresses('eth0')[netifaces.AF_INET][0]['addr']
print(ip)
```

`eth0` is just an example, you can get the actual interface name from `ipconfig`